# Activity is empty When email client is opened and come back to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, email-client

I am opening email client using intent from the app. After opening email client and comeback to activity the activity is getting cleared. onCreate is getting called when we come back to activity. The values which I set on activity using static variable, everything will be cleared and the activity is empty after sending the email and come back to activity. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think your application gets closed because onCreate isn't called when you resume your application

Comment: Are you getting any error??

Comment: No errors, I don't know why it is getting reloaded...

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right than you need to save the state of all controls in the `onSaveInstanceState` callback.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", yourTextView.getText().toString());
}
```

When you app restarts you can read the value with the `onCreate` callback like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) { // is null on first start
        yourTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("MyString"));
        //...
    }
    // ...
}
```